# Unity change scene with button

Tags: unity, c#, scenemanager

I already understand how to do this but the problem I'm having is:

When I go from "MainMenu" to "Level01" and then back, the buttons lose their reference. How can I fix this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static LevelManager Instance;
    public static int CurrentScene;

    private void Start()
    {
        if(Instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            Instance = this;
        }
        //LevelManagerStartup();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            if(CurrentScene != 0)
            {
                LoadScene(CurrentScene);
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M))
        {
            if(CurrentScene != 0)
            {
                LoadScene(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void LoadScene(int BuildIndex)
    {
        CurrentScene = BuildIndex;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(BuildIndex);
        if(CurrentScene == 0)
        {
            LevelManagerStartup();
        }
    }

    private void LevelManagerStartup()
    {
        //get a refarance to the highscoer manager
        Debug.Log(CurrentScene);
        if(CurrentScene == 0)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;
            RefButtons();
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }
        //make sure this stuff working.
        Debug.Log("LevelManager");
    }

    private void RefButtons()
    {
        GameObject ButtonHolder = GameObject.Find("ButtonHolder");
        Button[] buttons = new Button[3];
        for(int i = 0; i < ButtonHolder.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            buttons[i] = ButtonHolder.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>();
            buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => LoadScene(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific reference are you losing? Walk us through how you've set up your project and the specific symptoms of the problem you're observing.

Comment: Yes the LevelManager is an instantance in the MainScene and it is neither DoNotDestroyOnLoad nor does it get deleted on load. but i'm using a singleton pattern, how that works is when the Start is called then a new copy is made and replaces the old LevelManager instance. Therefor the reference is lost, i don`t know why this happens. Hope this is clear Thanks for response.

Answer (score -1):

To solve I made everything static.

Comment: If this fixed your issue, you might want to mark the answer as accepted.